# как получить soup на странице которая имеет загрузку

Tags: python, xml, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Захотелось спарсить [с этого сайта](https://fantasy-worlds.org/lib/id25365/read/) книгу, парсить сайты которые загружают свой код сразу я более-менее умею, а такие как эти - нет. Как получить soup с этого сайта после загрузки книги?

Изменено:
получил XML файл, как теперь получить из него, к примеру, название книги?
Я попробовал так, но не получилось:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET


def getBookName(tree):
    return tree.find('description/title-info/book-title').text

print(getBookName(ET.parse('fileToParse.xml')))
```

Comment: в XHR есть адрес https://fantasy-worlds.org/module/get_fb2.php?id=25365, который возвращает xml с книгой

Comment: спасибо, у меня получилось получить XML файл. Как теперь к примеру получить название книги? Я написал код с которым я пробовал это сделать, но у меня не получилось.

Comment: получить название книги

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант, как спарсить xml с помощью того же BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


>>> url = 'https://fantasy-worlds.org/module/get_fb2.php?id=25365'
>>> r = requests.get(url)

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
>>> title = soup.find('book-title')
>>> title.text
'Союз проклятых'

>>> annotation = soup.find('annotation')
>>> annotation.text.strip()
'После того как клан «Стальных Крыс» обманом завладел Костяным Мечом и продал его другому клану, Фальк вновь возвращается в Арктанию, чтобы попытаться вернуть квестовый предмет. Теперь на кону не только выполнение задания виртуальной богини, но и вполне реальная человеческая жизнь. Но все не так просто – в игре его на каждом шагу терроризируют «крысы», пытаясь заставить выложить всю информацию о местонахождении остальных эпических артефактов, представляющих не только игровую, но и немалую финансовую ценность. Да и новый владелец Костяного Меча едва ли захочет расстаться со столь ценным приобретением, и Фальку решительно нечего предложить ему в обмен. Но выход найдется всегда, пусть ради этого и придется нарушить закон…'

>>> author = soup.find('author')
>>> print(f"author: {author.find('first-name').text} {author.find('last-name').text}")
author: Алекс Кош
```

Comment: спасибо, получилось.